# Como criar um vetor com datas que se repetem?

Tags: r, data.frame

Preciso criar um vetor com datas sequenciais entre 01/01/2013 e 31/05/2018, porém com repetições, conforme exemplo abaixo, associadas a hora.

`01/01/2013 0:00
01/01/2013  1:00
01/01/2013  4:00
01/01/2013  8:00
01/01/2013  12:00
01/01/2013  18:00
02/01/2013  0:00
02/01/2013  1:00
02/01/2013  4:00
02/01/2013  8:00
02/01/2013  12:00
02/01/2013  18:00
03/01/2013  0:00
03/01/2013  1:00
03/01/2013  4:00
03/01/2013  8:00
03/01/2013  12:00
03/01/2013  18:00`

Como posso fazer isso de modo automático?

Comment: Já tentou fazer algo? Compartilhe conosco com está seu código até o momento.

Comment: Sei apenas criar o vetor de datas desse modo `data <- seq(as.Date('2013/01/01', "%Y/%m/%d"), as.Date('2018/05/31', "%Y/%m/%d"), 1)`. Porém não sei como determinar repetições.

Comment: Consegui. Não havia me atentado que posso alterar o 1 do final da função para frações de dia. Obrigada!

Comment: @AndreiaAlmeida você pode responder a sua própria pergunta! é uma boa prática deixar a resposta para que outros também encontrem em futuras pesquisas.

Answer (score 4):

Apesar da sua resposta à sua pergunta, vou também responder. Isto por dois motivos.

1. Nos dados da pergunta cada dia está repetido 6 vezes e com `by = 0.5` só repete duas.
2. Há também as horas, que faltam na sua resposta.

Em primeiro lugar, começo por criar um vetor de datas. Modifiquei um pouco o seu `seq/as.Date` para tornar mais claro o incremento `by = "days"`. A segunda instrução repete cada dia as tais 6 vezes.
Note que `data` é uma função R base, por isso chamei a esse vetor `Data`.

```
Data <- seq(as.Date('2013/01/01', "%Y/%m/%d"), as.Date('2018/05/31', "%Y/%m/%d"), by = "days")
Data <- rep(Data, each = 6)
```

Em segundo lugar, crio um vetor de classe `"character"` com as horas. Também há uma função `seq.POSIXt` mas neste caso não pode ser utilizada porque os incrementos das horas não são constantes, as diferenças de horas dos dados da pergunta são `1 3 4 4 6`.

```
Hora <- c("0:00", "1:00", "4:00", "8:00", "12:00", "18:00")
Hora <- rep(Hora, length.out = length(Data))
```

Finalmente, crio uma `data.frame` com os dois vetores na mesma coluna.

```
dados <- data.frame(Data = as.POSIXct(paste(Data, Hora), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))

head(dados, n = 20)
#                  Data
#1  2013-01-01 00:00:00
#2  2013-01-01 01:00:00
#3  2013-01-01 04:00:00
#4  2013-01-01 08:00:00
#5  2013-01-01 12:00:00
#6  2013-01-01 18:00:00
#7  2013-01-02 00:00:00
#8  2013-01-02 01:00:00
#9  2013-01-02 04:00:00
#10 2013-01-02 08:00:00
#11 2013-01-02 12:00:00
#12 2013-01-02 18:00:00
#13 2013-01-03 00:00:00
#14 2013-01-03 01:00:00
#15 2013-01-03 04:00:00
#16 2013-01-03 08:00:00
#17 2013-01-03 12:00:00
#18 2013-01-03 18:00:00
#19 2013-01-04 00:00:00
#20 2013-01-04 01:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

O vetor pode ser obtido a partir da função `seq(from, to, by= )`, indicando o ponto final da sequência, designado pelo by, conforme exemplo abaixo.

`> data <- seq(as.Date('2013/01/01', "%Y/%m/%d"), as.Date('2018/05/31', "%Y/%m/%d"), 1)`
 `> data
    [1] "2013-01-01" "2013-01-02" "2013-01-03" "2013-01-04" "2013-01-05"...`

Alterando o número 1 ao final da função, que permite um intervalo diário, é possível obter valores subdiários.

`> data <- seq(as.Date('2013/01/01', "%Y/%m/%d"), as.Date('2018/05/31', "%Y/%m/%d"), 0.5)`
 `> data
    [1] "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-02" "2013-01-02" "2013-01-03" "2013-01-03"...`